# Big Endian System - different output for same input

Tags: c, endianness

I am newbie to big endian system and trying to understand basic behaviour in it. I observed even when I assign same value to different data type, the value for u64 is different, while little endian system has same result.

Psuedo-Code and Explanation for above problem statement:

```
union types {
        uint8_t  u8;
        uint16_t u16;
        uint32_t u32;
        uint64_t u64;
};
```

I am assigning 1 to each type and print u64 values. Sample Code;

```
union types a={0};

a.u8 = 1;
printf("A. u64 %016lx\n", a.u64);

a.u16 = 1;
printf("B. u64 %016lx\n", a.u64);

a.u32 = 1;
printf("C. u64 %016lx\n", a.u64);

a.u64 = 1;
printf("D. u64 %016lx\n", a.u64);
```

In Big Endian System results are different

```
A. u64 0100000000000000
B. u64 0001000000000000
C. u64 0000000100000000
D. u64 0000000000000001
```

While in little endian system, result is always same (0x1).

Can someone please explain why is this so ? Is there any value we can assign which will have same values for all types in big endian System as we have in little endian?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You realized that this effect is related to endianess. After reading any resource about endianess, how does the result differ from what you expected? BTW: Assigning a value to a member of a union and reading from another member causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense.  Do you understand what big-endian means?  Do you understand what little-endian means?  Presumably not.  So, look it up and read about it, rather than posting questions like this.  And to answer your specific query, how about this:  If the union is initially all zero, then assigning zero to any of its members should presumably leave it as zero.  Is that what you were looking for?  You could probably do the same with all ones.  Other than that, big- vs. little-endian will probably behave differently.

Comment: `a.u8 = 1;` you assigned 1 byte but didn't initialize the whole union so reading the reaming bytes invokes UB

Comment: @phuclv `union types a={0};` should set the entire union to zero per C11 6.7.9.1p21, no?

Comment: @phuclv It is _well-defined_ as per 6.7.9 §10 ("and any padding is initialized to zero bits") §19 §21.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The initialization of the union may set all bytes to zero, but the assignments cause the other bytes to have unspecified values because C 2018 6.2.6.1 7 says “When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values.”

Comment: @phuclv: Per C 2018 6.2.6.1 7, after a union member is assigned, the other bytes in the union take unspecified values. An unspecified value is a valid value with no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance (3.19.3), and using it produces unspecified behavior (3.4.4), not undefined behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was merely commenting on the *initialization*.  I assumed the OP's code was imply minimized too much and omitted clearing the union, as it's obviously not complete.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Why do you say `union types a={0};` should set the entire union to zero? I do not see that in the C standard. C 2018 6.7.9 10 says padding is initialized to zero bits, but padding is different from bytes that correspond to union members other than the one initialized. (E.g., 6.2.6.1 6 and 7 distinguish padding bytes from bytes of union members other than the one being modified.) On top of that, 6.7.9 10 only applies to an object that is not initialized explicitly. I do not see anything that says what the padding bytes of a union that is initialized are initialized to.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: 6.7.9.1 21 applies to aggregates. Aggregates are arrays and structures, not unions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil There's a reason why I ended that comment with a question mark - I was frankly waiting for your opinion.  I thought you'd be here earlier than this.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Big endian is also for network where data msb starts at first or lower address and address increments and lsb reaches. For the output that you gave it is correct that way. lsb for u8 u16 u32 and u64 are 1 while rest are zeros. msb is the first byte of buffer. Little endian will have lsb at start address which is first address of buffer and it is easy to see why it is always 0x1 for print of union hex buffer. msb for little endian will be at next highest address for datatype size. Though note that pointer values of u8 u16 u32 u64 if you print for little endian and big endian and interpret that will give further clarity.